# getStylesheets().add(...) not working with Windows (7)

Tags: java, css, javafx, stylesheet

(Scroll down for solution)

I've made a program with JavaFX with Linux. I use

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
            "file:" + Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/style/stylesheet.css").toString());
```

to load my stylesheet into the application. This works under Linux but not under Windows. Whatever I do it always says

```
Aug 01, 2015 5:53:42 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStyleSheetUnPrivileged
Warning: Resource "file:C:\Users\win7\Desktop\resources\style\stylesheet.css" not found.
```

Anyone an idea what's the problem her? Any keywords?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I've tried

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
            "file:///" + Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/style/stylesheet.css").toString());
```

and

```
    URI stylesheetURI = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/style/stylessheet.css").toUri();
    scene.getStylesheets().add(stylesheetURI.toString());
```

and

```
    Path stylesheetPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/style/stylessheet.css");
    scene.getStylesheets().add(stylesheetPath.toUri().toString());
```

**SOLUTION:**
I've got it working for Linux and Windows with the following code:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(Paths.get("./resources/style/stylesheet.css").toAbsolutePath().toUri().toString());
```

with the help of @RealSkeptic and @brian. Thanks!

Comment: You can leave off ./ (not just the . or it will be root dir) . I just put it to show it's the current dir.  It's useful to remember since if the resources folder was one level up from the jar file, you could use ../resources/etc.  One . is current dir, .. is up a level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user.dir is just the current dir where the program was started.  Put a . to say it's a path relative to the current dir.  Then convert it to a proper string as shown.

```
File f = new File("./resources/style/stylesheet.css");
scene.getStylesheets().add(f.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

add: I looked up the definition of user.dir and the java people don't use the terminology current dir.  Instead, they say

> "user.dir"    User working directory

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the appropriate way to create a "file" URI is to add three slashes before the drive letter: `C:\something\something` becomes `file:///C:/something/something`.

Better yet, since you are using a `Path`, simply use `Path.toUri()`. It will do this properly for you both on Linux and on Windows.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried what you suggested but it didn't do the trick. Using `Path.toUri()` needs `.toString()` to fit for `add(...)` and produces the String `file:///C:\something\somethinig\...` that throws the same exception. Linux works fine.

Comment: @parboiledRice Can you add the code where you did that to your question? I'm not sure all the parts of the path are connected correctly. Also, are you sure that the file is actually there?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your development setup, but I usually grab resources from the JAR file created by my IDE. If you are using fxml, you can start with the URL passed as an argument to the `start()` method. Then I use something like the following:

```
        private String getCssFileLocation() {
            String locInJar = "/net/clarkonium/jist/resources/css/help.css";
            System.out.println("fxml URL: " + fxmlUrl);
            String externalForm = fxmlUrl.toExternalForm();
            System.out.println("fxmUrl.toExternalForm(): " + externalForm);
            String prefix = externalForm.substring(0, externalForm.indexOf("!") + 1);
            System.out.println("prefix: " + prefix);
            String resLocation = prefix + locInJar;
            System.out.println("resLocation: " + resLocation);
            return resLocation;
        }
```

Since my program knows the location of the resource it wants, it pastes that on the URL in place of the fxml location. A run of the program produced this output showing the steps the function takes:

```
fxml URL: jar:file:/C:/projects/Jist/dist/run786853897/Jist.jar!/net/clarkonium/jist/RepositorySetup.fxml
fxmUrl.toExternalForm(): jar:file:/C:/projects/Jist/dist/run786853897/Jist.jar!/net/clarkonium/jist/RepositorySetup.fxml
prefix: jar:file:/C:/projects/Jist/dist/run786853897/Jist.jar!
resLocation: jar:file:/C:/projects/Jist/dist/run786853897/Jist.jar!/net/clarkonium/jist/resources/css/help.css
```

Then you can use the location returned to add the stylesheet.

All the stuff before the exclamation point is dependent on my IDE and changes from run to run. This method also works after development is finished and the program is run from another location.